# Javascript Date.now() function

Tags: javascript

I am new into JS , started few weeks ago. The issue  I am having an issue with the **Date.now()** function.It's a very basic code , please go through it .

```js
start = Date.now();
console.log(start);
setTimeout(count, 7000);

function count() {
  stop = Date.now();
  console.log(stop, start, stop - start);
}
```

And console output is

```
1600149626005 1600149618993 7012
```

Now, its clearly visible that its not equals to the delay that I have provided(7012!=7000).Moreover the result is different each and every time I run the code.**Is this extra 12 ms, due to the code execution time or due to  something else?**

Comment: Nothing is wrong with `Date.now()` - it gives you the correct time. `setTimeout` is not precise - it is a *minimum* delay before running the function but it might take a bit more (12ms is normal) depending on what else is running.

Comment: okay...understood.
Thanks mate :)

Comment: I get 0 and 1 millisecond delays when I run that in Chrome's JavaScript console.

Comment: you should learn about the event loop, task que to understand why setTimeout has an delay

Comment: Before you downvote this question, consider that it has everything a question should have including working code, expectations and actual results. Nobody had to post any comments asking for clarification. Good question @DipChakraborty

Comment: @DipChakraborty that being said, next time make sure you search first 

Comment: @Phil... Actually  I was in a bit of rush,  so I didn't search about this,  thanks tho.